# Extracting embedded data from mongo object ( sub fields) in Talend

Tags: mongodb, object, extract, etl, talend

I'm working on Talend open studio for Big Data and connected to a MongoDB Database ,
however i can't extract complex subfields objects from my collections,
sometimes there is 4 levels of subfields and i always get a null when i try to extract more than the 1st level of data inside a sub field.
can you please help me ?
Thank you <3

Answer (score 0):

Use get and set methods. Only For data that is non persistent.

Comment: how can i use get and set methods in talend (ps : i'm new to it )

Comment: This should be added as comment, not a separate answer. you will be able to add comment after gaining some reputations.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the whole JSON object by writing a * to the DB column name field in the schema.

Once you have the raw json you could get the information from it a lot easier.

Comment: can you send a screenshot plz